# Что лучше выбрать bgsound или audio?

Tags: javascript

Хочи проигрывать звук в браузере. Нашёл два способа: bgsound и audio. Какой из них лучше выбрать (чтобы поддерживалось большинствами браузеров)?

Answer (score 1):

bgsound хреново поддерживается браузерами и еще хуже скриптуется.

Comment: Ок, понял. Значит будем использовать audio.

Comment: Хм, почему мой камент окуклился и стал ответом?